# Windows: How to symlink drive to another drive?

Tags: windows, symlink

I have a client whose data has been moved from the H drive to the I drive, but their Access export script seems to have hardcoded the H drive as the destination even though it no longer exists on the new system. How would I create an H drive that maps to the I drive? I'm a unix/linux guy.

I'm guessing something like `mklink /d H: I:`? Would that work?

Comment: My recommendation would be "don't"... Tell the devs to fix their program. On the other hand, you should be able to reassign the drive letters through the Computer Management interface, but what if someone else has hardcoded `I:` in the meantime...?

Comment: I guess the best way would be to export script. I just wanted to see a second option just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, mklink isn't going to do it for you.  What you need to do is to create a virtual hard drive (VHD) and copy the client's data to it. (Or modify the export script, which is the best thing to do.) I used Windows 7 to test my instructions below.

Start-> run-> diskmgmt.msc (accept all defaults... I'm not doing anything special below)

From the menu bar select Action -> Create VHD

Choose the location and name the file (which will be the vhd) and specify the size and click OK.

Right click on the Disk # (underneath will be Unknown and the size and "Not Initialized"). Select "Initialize Disk" & click OK

Right click on the black bar of the unallocated disk space and select "new simple volume". A wizard opens up an on the second page it lets you assign the drive letter. Complete the wizard and you're done!

Comment: worked perfectly debi. Thanks a lot!! I couldn't find any other solution. No clue how to change the path inside of access

Answer (score 4):

You can use good old SUBST command for that
"subst H: I:"
Create some startup CMD to make it available after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Map a network drive to \\localhost\H$ and set it to Drive I.