# Simulate a D:/ drive folder to be a C:/ drive folder

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, server, directory

I have an ASP.Net website running on Windows Server 2012. Visitors can download content that is stored in two folders. These folders are located in the website's own folder structure.

However, I'm running out of space so I want to add a D:/ drive and I want one of the folders to move to the D:/ drive.

So my question is; How can I fool IIS to think the content is still located in that same C:/ folder?

To make things more complicated, I CANNOT change the website. It's an old website, the project is lost.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18112515/11683) would have worked, but given that C and D are going to exist as actual drives, it won't.

Comment: Are you sure the website uses direct file system paths, as opposed to `Server.MapPath` or the sort?

Comment: @GSerg Yes and no. The download links do point to the same path as it is on the server but the download request do first go through the "ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)" handler. A few checks are being done there but in the end the file is located as given by the "context.Request.Path" parameter.

Comment: I'm currently trying this on my own computer: First I delete one of the folders. In IIS I create a virtual folder inside the web application at where the folder should be and I point the physical path to some other folder on my computer. This seems to work.